# Shotwell doesn't show folder in home directory when importing

Tags: shotwell

In the `Import from Folder` option window, the folder where my photos are located is not displayed when I navigate to the home directory. I tried to drag the folder to the Shotwell but it says:

> 1 non-image file skipped.

When I try to *Save Details* the saved log can't be found anywhere on the system.

Did anyone had similar issues with folders being non-visible?

I installed Shotwell to my other PC and encountered no such problem. I am using Xubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved when I removed the version I installed from Flatpak and installed it by the official repository.

Comment: I had similar experiences with other desktop apps, as Skype... these Flatpak, Snap, and etc are a real mess (why on earth would I want Skype running in a kind of container???)...